# How much water should I give to a 20 foot Italian Cypress tree?

Tags: trees, watering

I have an Italian cypress tree in my backyard which is about 20 feet tall.

How much water should I give it?
Also, how frequently should I water it?

I should point out a big caveat.  The tree is dying and starting to turn orange.  It might be dead already.  The main cause of this is the California drought and my lack of watering it.  It's been alive for at least 20 years (without any external water intervention).  But now I fear it's dying (or dead) and the lack of rain is accelerating it's death.
[image]

[image]

Comment: pictures please, lack of water may not be the problem

Comment: Oh please send pictures.  If this guy has done well all this time without additional water, very suspicious.  Have you stopped watering the lawn and other plant beds?  Water moves laterally more than vertically and this tree might be missing the water normally given to the lawn.  PLEASE send pictures and as much information as you can.  When did you first notice the yellowing?  Where is it located?  Fertilizer?  How often?

Comment: @stormy , I added a couple of pictures.

Comment: @stormy , to answer your questions, I first started noticing the yellowing about 1 month ago, but by then it was definitely orange.  It was probably orange even earlier, but I only noticed about 1 month ago.  The tree is located in my yard and at times that area might be under-watered.  There is a sprinkler system that waters twice a week, but it might not be reaching the tree.  There is no fertilizer used around the tree.

Comment: there are a few ratios around, an average seems to be 5gal per inch (diameter of trunk at 4 feet).  personally i go by experience\instinct\feel but that's kind of hard over the inter-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks sadly dying to me :( did you check for diseases? We have never watered them in France where we lived before, not even during 4 months droughts. They seem to but down some very deep roots. Please look further in for parasites or diseases.

Comment: Just for the record, the tree died  =(